# How can i store other request, when i change one request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

When i equal my request with 2 objects. When i change one, the other is automatically changed. How can i store second one like a old request. You can find what I mean below. How can i store second one ?

```js
app.post('/example', (request, response) => {
    const data = request.body;
    const copy = request.body;

    //This is a basic example of my problem in node.js
    //Example request.body[0].execution = 10

    data[0].execution = 5;
    console.log(data[0].execution);  // it shows 5
    console.log(copy[0].execution);  // it shows 5, I dont know why ? I need 10 like request

});
```

Comment: Assignment is **not** copying.

Comment: you need deep copy, const copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(request.body))

Comment: @Nonik Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try Deep Copying instead of Shallow

`const newCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(old));`

or simply

`const newCopy = {...old}`